# XPath, select group containing a given element with a given name

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml code:

```
[...]
                        <group>
                            <field name="code"/>
                            <field name="return_picking_type_id"/>
                            <field name="barcode_nomenclature_id" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
                        </group>
[...]
```

Which would be the XPath syntax to select this `<group>` tag (the one which contains `<field name="code">` tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work

```
'//group[field[@name="code"]]'
```